# Deep equal on function value

Tags: go

From `reflect` package, I use `DeepEqual` function check similarity of both value. It works until I use function as value.

```
package main
import "fmt"
import "reflect"

type thisHandler func(s string) 

func main() {
    var a thisHandler = func(s string) {
        fmt.Println(s)
    }
    
    b := a
    c := a
    fmt.Println(b)
    fmt.Println(c)
    fmt.Println(reflect.DeepEqual(b,c))
}
```

[Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/sfX78IRLWCY)

Why can't `DeepEqual` check similarity of value of a function?

Comment: The [reflect.DeepEqual documentation](https://pkg.go.dev/reflect#DeepEqual) says *Func values are deeply equal if both are nil; otherwise they are not deeply equal.*  This is because function values can only be compared to nil as stated in [the specification](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Comparison_operators).

Answer (score 0):

Based on it's documentation said:
https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#DeepEqual

> ...
> Func values are deeply equal if both are nil; otherwise they are
> not deeply equal.
> ...
> In general DeepEqual is a recursive relaxation
> of Go's == operator. However, this idea is impossible to implement
> without some inconsistency. Specifically, it is possible for a value
> to be unequal to itself, either because it is of func type
> (uncomparable in general)...